# Cannot figure out how to save this field into database, save a list of Integer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this entity :

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipes")
data class Recipe(
        @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
        val categories: List<Int>,
        val picture: String,
        @Embedded(prefix = "time")
        val time: Time,
        val people: Int,
        val difficulty: Int,
        val price: Int,

        @Embedded(prefix = "ingredients")
        @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
        val ingredients: List<Ingredient>,

        @Embedded(prefix = "utensils")
        @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
        val utensils: List<Utensil>,

        @Embedded(prefix = "steps")
        @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
        val steps: List<Step>,

        val createdAt: String,
        val updatedAt: String
) : Serializable
```

And when I compile it, I got

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> categories = null;
```

Problem is, I added the TypeConverter, it's in my class Converters :

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromIntList(value: List<Int>): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
    return gson.toJson(value, type)
}

@TypeConverter
fun toIntList(value: String): List<Int> {
    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type
    return gson.fromJson(value, type)
}
```

It should work since it knows that it should transforma list of Int to strings.
Futhermore, I got this error which I dont know where it can come from, and I have it like 5 times.

```
 Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty
  constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

I added the nested class like Ingredient, Step, Ustensil but I dont post the code since it should not be related.